# Python: Call by Reference and Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I try to parse an XML file.
The main goal is to get an specific tag with with an other specific parent tag.
I have to use an already existing file and i have to modify it.

```
def get_item_with_parents(self, parent, name, items=None, parents=None):
    self.parents=parents

    if items == None:
        top_level = 1
        items = []
        self.parents = []
    else:
        top_level = 0

    for child in self.children:
        self._append_list(child.name)
        if child.name == name and parent in self.parents:
            print "inside if"
            self._del_list()
            items.append(child)
            #print self.parents
            child.get_item_with_parents(parent, name, items, self.parents)

    if top_level:
        return PacketList(items)


def _append_list(self, item):
    self.parents.append(item)


def _del_list(self):
    self.parents=[]
    print "test"
    print self.parents
```

The code should do the following (the child variable should basically mean the same as the parent thing):

I get the parent tag an the name of the tag which should be returned.
Then I check if I am the first recursion otherwise i will not return the packetlist at the end.

For each child I try to append its name to my self.parents list. Then I check if my packet has the right "name" and if yes I look if the "parent" is in self.parent.
So there occurs the problem now.

If the parent was in the list, I have to delete everything in my list. But this wont work.

The list will not be cleared. So if there is a next occurance of the tag with the name "name", it will be appended again even if it should not do, because the parent should not be in the list anymore

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: "But this wont work." does *not* have a meaning. Please clarify what do you mean by "wont work". Does it raise an error? (If so post the full traceback you get) Does it give an unexpected result? (If so post the result you are getting [with relative inputs] *and* the expected result you wanted)

Comment: Yea.. you are right. Sorry, it just does nothing. The list will not be cleared. So if there is a next occurance of the tag with the name "name", it will be appended again even if it should do not, because the parent should not be in the list anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my misstake.
To clear a list i hav to call `del parents[:]`

`parents=[]` does not work(it seams it does simply nothing).